# Speed up converting huge 4D arrays to 5D arrays (converting 5D multidimensional image)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance, h5py

I am trying to convert huge 5D HD5 images (read using h5py) into arrays that can be read by Napari. However, I can only extract 3D stacks of it (Z,X,Y) so I have to iterate over channel and time and combine all the 4D arrays into a 5D array. However, it takes about 1 minute per time point so it could take over an hour for each data file with my current code.

Currently, I am appending all the arrays into of each channel into a list, converting the list to an array and then storing in another list. After going over all timepoints, I convert the list into an array. I tried appending all to a list first then converting to array, tried stacking the arrays as I go but all seem to be very slow. Any ideas on how to speed this faster and/or convert the multichannel image to an array faster? Thank you!

```
combined_list = []
for i in timepoints:
  im = file.get('DataSet')
  res0 = im.get('ResolutionLevel 0')
  data = res0.get('TimePoint '+ str(i))
  auto = data.get('Channel 0')
  stack1 = auto.get('Data')
  auto = data.get('Channel 0')
  stack2 = auto.get('Data')

  combined_stack = np.asarray([stack1,stack2])
  combined_list.append(combined_stack)
image = np.asarray(combined_list)
```

For reference, an image is about (60,3,48, 2048, 5888) (TCZYX)

Comment: First, I suggest creating [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You will get better help by helping people reproducing the issue. Next, maybe creating empty array and writing into it will be faster? You could write to the array as you extract each 3D stack. At the very least, it should decrease memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing A LOT of data manipulation: 1) appending arrays to a list, 2) converting the list to an array, 3) storing in another list, and 4) finally converting the 2nd list into an array. I'm 99% sure that will cause performance issues. Instead, create the target `image` array (as an appropriately size empty array), then read and load the data directly to it. So much simpler and faster.

What do you mean by *"I can only extract 3D stacks of it (Z,X,Y)"*? h5py datasets can be sliced using NumPy notation, so it should be "relatively easy" to slice and stack the data you want (if you understand the schema).

Given the lack of details in your post, I need more info to write the answer.  Please document the H5 file schema. Or as @dankal444 said, provide a minimal, reproducible example with a similar schema.

I tried to create an example file to mimic yours, but can't infer the schema from your code. See comments below:

This makes sense:

```
im = file.get('DataSet')
```

It reads the H5 dataset named 'DataSet' and returns as array `im`:
What is the dtype and shape of `im`?

What are you trying to do with this line?

```
res0 = im.get('ResolutionLevel 0')
```

It is dictionary `.get()` syntax applied a numpy array (which is not valid):

The `.get()` syntax continues with `data`, `auto` and `stack1/stack2`

```
data = res0.get('TimePoint '+ str(i))
auto = data.get('Channel 0')
stack1 = auto.get('Data')
auto = data.get('Channel 0')
stack2 = auto.get('Data')
```

Finally, it looks like `stack1` and `stack2` reference the same objects -- is that a typo?